# Referencing javascript array using variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables

I'm attempting to reference a value in an array through the use of a variable.

So, given `myarray`, I can do the following just fine:

```
alert(myarray[1].hp_id);
```

The contents I'm after comes out just fine.

**However,** if I want to put `hp_id` in a variable, it doesn't work so well.

```
var array_col = hp_id;
alert(myarray[1].array_col);
```

How might I be able to make reference to an array value by using a variable?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do it this way

```
var array_col = 'hp_id';
alert(myarray[1][array_col]);
```

Answer (score 1):

using "dot notation" to reference key names only references things with that literal name, as though you were doing `myarray[1]["array_col"]`. Use `myarray[1][array_col]` to use a variable for the key name.